# How to cancel suspended method by timeout?

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

I know how I can cancel method executing by timeout. I mean `Task-Wait-Timeout-CancellationToken` trick. I.e. method is wrapped in Task. This technique works fine. For example:

```
private void TestConnectMethod()
{
    int QueryTimeOut = 1000; //in ms

    _txtError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
               token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            Debug.WriteLine("Iteration" + DateTime.Now);
        }

    }, token).ContinueWith(t =>
    {

    });

    var wres = task.Wait(QueryTimeOut);

    if (!wres)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _txtError.Text = "Timeout!";
    }
    else
    {
        _txtError.Text = "All is ОК";
    }
}
```

Task will be cancelled succesfully. But what if Task look like this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // This is a server method that can be suspended
        ArchiveServiceClient.Instance.Authenticate()
    }, token).ContinueWith(t =>
    {

    });
```

`ArchiveServiceClient.Instance.Authenticate()` method can suspend application if server doesn't respond. Now, I cannot write

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

because these strings will be useless. How can I stop `Task` executing with suspended method? Is it possible?

Comment: 1) If the method you're calling doesn't support timeouts/cancellation you can't stop it gracefully. 2) But why would this suspend the application? Shouldn't it simply block the thread it's running on? 3) Why are you using `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` instead of `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, 2) - you right, it only blocks thread, but for me it is unacceptable too. 3) It doesn't matter here, both approaches work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't cancel execution of *any* code.

The sample you've posted first, assumes, that code supports graceful cancellation pattern. Of course, this isn't true for every method/class/library, what `ArchiveServiceClient.Instance.Authenticate` demonstrates.

(There are some tricks with `Tread.Abort`, but you should avoid them, because they are more harmful, than useful, and you can't cancel unmanaged code this way).

The only reliable way to cancel something from .NET application is to put that something in separate process, and kill the process on timeout. Of course, this requires more complex approach, comparing to graceful cancellation.

Comment: Thx, how can I get Task's Thread to Abort it? (Just for fun). I don't see any fit property in task object.

Comment: Use `Thread.CurrentThread` within task's body. I'd not recommend to abort thread pool threads (by default task will use thread pool).

Comment: @ Dennis, unfortunately I need to abort task's thread from here `if (!wres)
    {
        
    }`